# Unable to loop the files from Jenkins workspace using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I just written the below groovy script to read list of files in the Jenkins workspace an check if there is any file name starts with report. If it's I need to print those values too.

```
  build.getWorkspace().list().each
  { 
    println it.getName()

    if(it.name.startsWith('report'))
    {
      println it
    }
  }
```

**Exception:**

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class:
>   Script1   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:243)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:221)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedGetProperty$0.callStatic(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:230)
>     at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:12)

How can I find out the list of files in workspace and filter them by using name using groovy?

Comment: this code should work except startWith('report') - > startsWith('report')

Comment: Sorry thats typo.. I used startsWith only but it doesn't work

Comment: check braces in your code. Looks like you have "it" outside of each scope